# Castle Windsor: Is there a way to override a component Id?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, registration

I have the following bit of registration code:

```
Component.For<IPublishingService>().ImplementedBy<UseStoredProcedureToPrintService>(),
Component.For<IConfirmationDialog<AutomatedTransaction>>().ImplementedBy<ShipmentConfirmationDialog>().Named("ShipmentConfirmationDialog"),
Component.For<IConfirmationService<AutomatedTransaction>>().ImplementedBy<SingleTransactionConfirmation>().ServiceOverrides(
    ServiceOverride.ForKey("shipmentDialog").Eq("ShipmentConfirmationDialog") ),
```

A requirement came down the line that in some instances the application is supposed to behave somewhat differently.  Great I thought, this is exactly what I was using Castle Windsor for to begin with.

So I wrote my new components and I register them first.  For example, I implement IPublishingService differently and register the new implementation first so that it is resolved over the default one above.  However, a problem occurrs in the few cases where I had no choice but to use an id to wire up my service overrides.  For example how do I redirect the ServiceOverride for ShipmentConfirmationDialog to use my new SpecialCaseShipmentConfirmationDialog implementation without modifying the bit of code above?

There are all sorts of mechanisms in castle windsor that I don't really understand like forwarding and ActAs that I'm hoping will provide a simple answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd keep it simple. If it's configurable, put it in the config (web.config / app.config) then just load the ID using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shipmentDialogToUse"];`

Also remember that the fluent registration API is not the be-all and end-all of registration. XML still has its time and place where it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: I think its the right tool for the job when you need to make changes to a deployed app.  Otherwise, just put all registration into Registrar classes and add a simple dynamic discovery mechanism which finds Registrar all local dlls.

In my case I have an app that can be deployed against 2 very different data bases so I need to deploy it with different model translation layers and a couple different UI screens.  Since all the configuration is deployment-time I don't really see why xml config is necessary (though I allow it too).

Point taken though. Still too bad there's no override mechanism.